# How to change hostingModel="OutOfProcess" while publishing to IISServer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I set HostingModel to "Out Of Process" in VS Debug window. But when publish the project to my DEV server. web.config file showing always `hostingModel="inprocess"`. If I remove this attribute I can run the application.

Is there any process while publishing we change `hostingModel` to `OutOfProcess`. I am using ASP.Net Core 3.1 version for WebAPI

[image]

Answer (score 12):

For Visual Studio 2019, changing the project file does not solve the problem.

The following line:

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

Should be added inside  in the publish profile "YourProfileName".pubxml file lying in the Properties/PublishProfiles/ project directory.

Answer (score 5):

You need to understand the hierarchy of .Net core in order to understand exactly what you need to know.

Where .NetCore read this configuration from:
**First:
 `web.config`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" hostingModel="InProcess"></aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The value `hostingModel="InProcess"` will override all other configuration existing in your project.

**Second:**
`publish profile`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <PublishUrl>bin\Release</PublishUrl>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <EnvironmentName>staging</EnvironmentName>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The relevant node is `AspNetCoreHostingModel`

**Third:**
`.csproj`

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
```

Any value you will have in `.csproj` or `publish profile` will get overridden by the `webconfig`.

Answer (score 3):

Change the properties in VS Debug window, the project's `launchsettings.json` file is updated synchronously, and `launchsettings.json` is for VS running the project. To configure an app for out-of-process hosting, set the value of the `<AspNetCoreHostingModel>` property to `OutOfProcess` in the project file (.csproj):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: in net 6 this is not working for me has this changed

Comment: This worked for me in Visual Studio 2022 for Mac with .net core 6.x

Answer (score 2):

You can change your project file. add

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

inside PropertyGroup

Comment: Any explanations?

Comment: This Works
You should add this to publish profiles under Properties>PublishProfiles>{FolderProfile.pubxml}