# Change AspNetCoreHostingModel During DevOps Deploy

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-devops, asp.net-core-7.0

I have a plethora of applications deploying to multiple environments. I want to change the asp net core hosting model to outofprocess as part of my release process in Azure DevOps.

I am currently deploying with 'Web Deploy' method and there appears to be app settings and configuration settings available as part of the release, but I cannot find how to specify it as a parameter.

Is there a flag I can apply in config settings?

```
Edit web app configuration settings following the syntax -key value. Value containing spaces should be enclosed in double quotes.
Example : -phpVersion 5.6 -linuxFxVersion: node|6.11
```

Or should I try it as an XML variable substitution? The .csproj file that Microsoft wants it defined in is XML but it's not an .xml file, so I'm not sure if it would work as expected. Also, the key would have to be present in that file already for the substitution to work, if it even supports csproj files.

```
Variables defined in the build or release pipelines will be matched against the 'key' or 'name' entries in the appSettings, applicationSettings, and connectionStrings sections of any config file and parameters.xml. Variable Substitution is run after config transforms.

Note: If same variables are defined in the release pipeline and in the environment, then the environment variables will supersede the release pipeline variables.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/out-of-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-7.0

I have been looking at this for some time but haven't found a solution for it yet. Has anyone already done something like this?
I will come back to update it if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My ultimate solution was not pretty, but it worked. All the three methods of setting this value ultimately instructs the build process to generate a web.config with the parameter 'inprocess' or 'outofprocess'

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68271160/5597085

For only the environment which I want to run out of process, I ran a powershell script:

```
$webConfig = "(buildpath)\web.config"
(Get-Content -Path $webConfig) -replace "inprocess", "OutOfProcess" | Set-Content -Path $webConfig
```

It worked fine.